# Inf*0 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan, infinity

I have the following line in my code:

```
 1 - sqrt(pi/2)*sig*sqrt(Eb)*theta_l*exp(theta_l^2*sig^2*Eb/2).*(1 + erf(-theta_l*sig*sqrt(Eb)/sqrt(2)));
```

When I evaluate this expression for the following parameters:
 `Eb = 6324.6;`
 `sig = 1/sqrt(2);`
 `theta = 0.7;`, I get Nan. I know that this comes from the product of Infinity by 0.

However when I tested the same line in Mathematica, the result was a finite value. How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problematic part of your function is `exp(Eb/2)`. The value of Eb is so large, that the result of its exponentiation cannot be represented by a double precision floating point number (The numerical precision in Mathematica is obviously higher, or dynamic probably at the cost of performance), so you get `Inf`.

However, you can just change the input units to your function to stop this happening. For example, if we define your function as an anonymous function ...

```
funky = @(Eb, sig, theta_l) ...
         1 - sqrt(pi/2)*sig*sqrt(Eb)*theta_l*exp(theta_l^2*sig^2*Eb/2) .* ...
         (1 + erf(-theta_l*sig*sqrt(Eb)/sqrt(2)));
```

Then

```
funky(6324.6 / 1000, (1/sqrt(2))/1000, 0.7 / 1000) == ...
funky(6324.6 / 1e6, (1/sqrt(2))/1e6, 0.7 / 1e6) == ...
funky(6324.6 / 1e10, (1/sqrt(2))/1e10, 0.7 / 1e10) % etc
```

Comment: Thanks learnvst for your answer. The problem is that I will need this value later on so I was hoping if one can do some modification in a way to have the finite value.

Comment: @kagami if your values are larger than base MATLAB (and/or your computer )  can handle,  you'll have to look into extended-precision libraries such as `gmp` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I need to combine this library with MATLAB or is it in another language?

Comment: You'll need to install the library and install a MATLAB package that calls it. I forget the name but it's on FileExchange.